# sqlcmd error with sql file but works running same statement in sql console

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I have this `file.sql`:

```
INSERT INTO "Parcelas" ("PlanEstudio", "LineaEstudio", "NIF", "Plan", "Cosecha", "Linea", "Modulo", "CombCoberturas", "Referencia", "Hoja", "Parcela", "Cultivo", "Variedad", "GrupoVarietal", "Comarca", "ProvSigPac", "TermSigPac", "AgreSigPac", "ZonaSigPac", "PoliSigPac", "ParcSigPac", "ReciSigPac", "Superficie", "Arboles", "Edad", "ProdPrinc", "ProdComp", "Precio", "ValorProcPrinc", "ValorProdComp", "PRE", "PRF", "RendAsig2021") 
VALUES (2022, 300, '43729050R', 2020, 2021, 300, '2', 2, 'K826975', 2, 11, 5, 26, '31-08', 9, 25, 900, 0, 0, 26, 371, 1, 0.86, 1016, 18, 35000, 0, 0.25, 8750, 0, 35000, 22229, 0);
```

And I get this error with `sqlcmd -i`:

```
$ /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S "$SERVER" -d "$DATABASE" -U "$USER" -P "$PASSWORD" -i a.sql
```

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server BBDD-DES, Line 1
> Incorrect syntax near 'Parcelas'.

But if I don't use `-i` and execute the same insert, I don't have problems:

```
$ /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S "$SERVER" -d "$DATABASE" -U "$USER" -P "$PASSWORD"
1> INSERT INTO "Parcelas" ("PlanEstudio", "LineaEstudio", "NIF", "Plan", "Cosecha", "Linea", "Modulo", "CombCoberturas", "Referencia", "Hoja", "Parcela", "Cultivo", "Variedad", "GrupoVarietal", "Comarca", "ProvSigPac", "TermSigPac", "AgreSigPac", "ZonaSigPac", "PoliSigPac", "ParcSigPac", "ReciSigPac", "Superficie", "Arboles", "Edad", "ProdPrinc", "ProdComp", "Precio", "ValorProcPrinc", "ValorProdComp", "PRE", "PRF", "RendAsig2021") VALUES (2022,300,'43729050R',2020,2021,300,'2',2,'K826975',2,11,5,26,'31-08',9,25,900,0,0,26,371,1,0.86,1016,18,35000,0,0.25,8750,0,35000,22229,0);
2>
```

Why I can't run this insert using a `.sql` file?

Comment: Your names don't need any brackets or quotes anyway, just remove them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, by default, `sqlcmd` does not enable quoted identifiers. As a result `"Parcelas"` is read as a a *literal* string, *not* as a delimited object name.

Considering that none of your objects appear to need delimit identified, you could just get rid of them, or alternatively use the T-SQL delimit identifier, brackets (`[]`). Though, in truth, it's best to pass the `-I` (Enable Quoted Identifiers) when using `sqlcmd`:

Note this proof of concept, for example:

```bash
touch test.sql
echo 'SELECT "name" from sys.databases;' > test.sql
sqlcmd -S localhost -i test.sql -U thom
```

This returns the following table:

```
    
----
name
name
name
name
name
name
name
name
name
name
name
name
name
name
name
name
name
name
```

Notice many rows with the value `name`. If I pass the `-I` switch, I get the actual database names:

```bash
sqlcmd -S localhost -i test.sql -U thom -I
```

```
name                                                                                                                            
--------------
master                                                                                                                          
tempdb                                                                                                                          
model                                                                                                                           
msdb                                                                                                                            
Sandbox                                                                                                                         
TestBed                                                                                                                         
TestBed_HDD                                                                                                                     
WebDB                                                                                                                           
UTF8                                                                                                                            
Wordpress                                                                                                                       
Temporal                                                                                                                        
CaseSensitive                                                                                                                   
Maintenance                                                                                                                     
TimDB                                                                                                                           
ImportSample                                                                                                                    
Utility                                                                                                                         
AdventureWorks                                                                                                                  
SpeedTest
```

---

Alternatively, you could switch to using the (currently in preview) [go-sqlcmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/tools/sqlcmd/go-sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver16#download-and-install-go-sqlcmd) tool, which is [open source](https://github.com/microsoft/go-sqlcmd). This does not default to quoted identifiers being off, and (in fact) removes the `-I` switch).

```bash
thom@neith:/tmp$ sqlcmd --version
sqlcmd: v0.15.4
        
Legal docs and information: aka.ms/SqlcmdLegal
Third party notices: aka.ms/SqlcmdNotices
thom@neith:/tmp$ touch test.sql
thom@neith:/tmp$ echo 'SELECT "name" from sys.databases;' > test.sql
thom@neith:/tmp$ sqlcmd -S ptah -i test.sql -U thom
Password:
name                                                                                                                            
-------
master                                                                                                                          
tempdb                                                                                                                          
model                                                                                                                           
msdb  
...
```